# Print a variable containing spaces in bash

Tags: bash

I have this string:
`string="I           love    spaces"`

I would like to print that so that the spaces would remain. `echo $string` doesn't seem to print the spaces as well.
Desired Output:

```
I           love    spaces
```

Comment: Glad that you sorted it out yourself. Anyways it is good to have a look [\[ here \]](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[bash]+%22print+string+with+spaces%22).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind me fellas. `echo "$string"` :/